# Android - Bind to a service from an other app

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have written 2 applications. `MyServiceApplication` and `MyActivityApplication`.
On boot I launch `MyService` which runs as a remote service. I want `MyActivityApplication` to communicate with it however `MyActivityApplication` does not have access to `MyServiceApplication` classes. All the examples I see online band an activity to a service in the following way:

```
bindService(new Intent(Binding.this, MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

My Application needs to communicate with `MyService`. The code is based off Google's `MessengerService` example.

The trouble as I mentioned earlier is that the service I'm trying to bind to was started by an other application whose sole purpose is to start this service.

Is there a way to do this where I can keep both applications independent? The idea is that I will have a second, third and fourth application all of whom may communicate with the same service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a shared library between your service and application that defines the interface you use to communicate with the bound service.

Comment: So what you're effectively saying is that my application should contain a jar that contains the classes for the Service? Or that they should have the same code base even if I create 2 separate applications?

Comment: You should have a library project http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html used by two applications. The library should include the binder of your bound service so that the binder can be used to 1) provide a binder interface from the service app. 2) be used to bind the second app to the service.

Comment: A different approach could be to use AIDL : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html. The "shared" library could be reduced to the whole aidl file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was such a thing as a library project. That does seem like a more manageable approach but I'll read both and figure stuff out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**
This solution and code example was valid at the time it was written at: 2015
Please look for other solution relevant for this day.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
You can define an intent-filer for your service with a specific action and bind to this service with intent assigned to this action.

MyServiceApplication:

```
<service android:name=".MyService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.some.action.NAME" />
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

MyActivityApplication:

```
bindService(new Intent("com.some.action.NAME"), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: This may have worked before but service intents must be explicit nowadays.

Comment: @JkJensen , you are right, as the answer was written at 2015. Nevertheless I do not think such answers should be downvoted (not just because this one is mine). Stackoverflow is a goto place for answers (including historical ones) and a better approach will be to  edit the answer and indicate the time the answer was relevant for.