# Test SOAP webservice without using soap client for a real-time feel

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I want to create two projects and deploy in 2 different tomcat servers.I want to start both the apps.Now I want to call a functionality of app1 in app2.App1 is having all the services and I want to call this service from app2.

Is it possible guys?

Comment: Yes , just try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Bind to a service from an other app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988359/android-bind-to-a-service-from-an-other-app)